# Why can't I reference all Opportunity Product (OpportunityLineItem) fields in formula fields?

Tags: formula-field, opportunity-lineitem

Salesforce's Spring '21 release finally offers [Opportunity Product (OpportunityLineItem) lookups](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_sales_features_core_opportunities_line_item_lookup.htm&release=230&type=5), which my organization has been waiting a long time for. However, we're having issues with our implementation, specifically around formula fields.

For some reason, formulas referencing certain standard OpportunityLineItem fields don't validate:
[image: ProductCode does not exist error]

I've tested with a number of different fields and I've encountered the issue inconsistently. I've found the the following fields error out:

- Opportunity_Line_Item__r.ProductCode
- Opportunity_Line_Item__r.Name
- Opportunity_Line_Item__r.Product2Id (and Product2.*)

But the following do not error out:

- Opportunity_Line_Item__r.CreatedById
- Opportunity_Line_Item__r.TotalPrice
- Opportunity_Line_Item__r.Discount
- Opportunity_Line_Item__r.Description

Why does the OpportunityLineItem lookup appear to be behaving differently in regards to formula field access?

Comment: can you do `Opportunity_Line_Item__r.PricebookEntry.Product2.ProductCode` ?

Comment: Yes, that appears to work just fine and is a perfect workaround. Thank you! Any idea on why the standard fields aren't accessible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround since accessing the `Product2` relationship from `OpportunityLineItem`, `QuoteItem`, or `OrderItem` has often given developers trouble is to use the `PricebookEntry` relationship:

- `Opportunity_Line_Item__r.PricebookEntry.Product2.ProductCode`
- `Opportunity_Line_Item__r.PricebookEntry.Product2ID`

etc